# react-native: final-form focus next field

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-final-form, final-form

I cant focus my next field with final-form and react-native and functional components. There is like 0 documentation on this case.

```
<Field
  component={TextField}
  name="title"
  returnKeyType={"next"}
  blurOnSubmit={false}
  onSubmitEditing={() => {
    _descriptionFieldRef.current.focus();
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's because I, the docs author, have never used react-native. Would love to include some if/when you figure it out!

Comment: @rendom have you found any solution yet!